# Select object variable based on option value match

Tags: javascript, attributes, html-select

I am having trouble finding a a method or function to actually make the appropriate var Check with the corresponding selected value as my selectedCheck to run through in my calculations. The reason I have it set it up as an object, was because there are several types of checks, each with different option values, quantitys and prices.

Here is my code so far:

```js
    function selectedCheck(current_quantity, current_price, projected_quantity, projected_price, optionValue) {
    this.current_quantity = current_quantity;
    this.current_price = current_price; 
    this.projected_quantity = projected_quantity;
    this.projected_price = projected_price;
    this.optionValue = function getValueFromOption() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("option").each().getAttribute("value");
    if (x === this.optionValue) { 

         /* Make the matching var check the selectedCheck */

        }
      };
    }

    /*Secure Plus Voucher Checks*/
    var check_11_50 = new selectedCheck(50, 66.99, 250, 169.99, "1785-00050/check-11");
    var check_11_250 = new selectedCheck(250, 169.99, 500, 230.99, "1785-00250/check-11");
    var check_11_500 = new selectedCheck(500, 230.99, 1000, 327.99, "1785-00500/check-11");
    var check_11_1000 = new selectedCheck(1000, 327.99, 2000, 514.99, "1785-01000/check-11");

  
    /*Calculations*/
    var current_pricepercheck = (selectedCheck.current_price - selectedCheck.current_quantity).toFixed(2);
    var projected_pricepercheck = (selectedCheck.projected_price - selectedCheck.projected_quantity).toFixed(2);
    var current_price_bulk = (selectedCheck.current_price / selectedCheck.current_quantity * selectedCheck.projected_quantity).toFixed(2);
    var projected_price_bulk = (selectedCheck.projected_price / selectedCheck.projected_quantity * selectedCheck.projected_quantity ).toFixed(2); 
    var savings = ( selectedCheck.current_price_bulk - selectedCheck.projected_price_bulk).toFixed(2);   
    document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = (savings.toFixed(2));
```

```html
    <select class="priceDrp5">
    <option value="1785-00050/check-11">50</option>
    <option selected="true" value="1785-00250/check-11">250</option>
    <option value="1785-00500/check-11">500</option> 
    <option value="1785-001000/check-11">1000</option>
    <option value="1785-002000/check-11">2000</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Sorry, I noticed a few things in my additional HTML which I hadn't updated, and I couldn't edit my original comment: http://jsfiddle.net/spencec6/emn8dp77/4/

Comment: are you opposed to using jquery?

Comment: No, jQuery should be fine

Comment: and you're hard-coding these values, they aren't being returned by a server call and subject to change, are they?

Comment: Yeah those are all hard-coded

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing calculations later with check object values, why not just do those when instantiating them. This could definitely be further optimized, but it works!! Btw, as you can see, I ended up not using jquery.

js fiddle (per usual) was acting wonky, so I wrote a [DEMO ON CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/2dd1a0465e93ea51756c578c761c0fe5?editors=101)

```
var checks = {};
function selectedCheck(quantity, price, projectedQuantity, projectedPrice, itemNumber) {
  var check = {
    pricePerCheck: (price - quantity).toFixed(2),
    projectedPricePerCheck: (projectedPrice - projectedQuantity).toFixed(2),
    priceBulk: (price / quantity * projectedQuantity).toFixed(2),
    projectedPriceBulk: (projectedPrice / projectedQuantity * projectedQuantity).toFixed(2),
    getSavings: function() { return (this.priceBulk - this.projectedPriceBulk).toFixed(2) } 
  };

  checks[itemNumber] = check;
}

selectedCheck(50, 66.99, 250, 169.99, "1785-00050/check-11");
selectedCheck(250, 169.99, 500, 230.99, "1785-00250/check-11");
selectedCheck(500, 230.99, 1000, 327.99, "1785-00500/check-11");
selectedCheck(1000, 327.99, 2000, 514.99, "1785-01000/check-11");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var priceDrpSelect = document.querySelector('.priceDrp5'),
      savings = document.getElementById("savings"),
      selectedCheck;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(checks, null, 4))
  priceDrpSelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var key = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value');
    selectedCheck = checks[key];
    savings.innerHTML = selectedCheck.getSavings();
  });
  priceDrpSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

Comment: the reason I had to do the calculations later is because my message is basically reading the selection from a site that already exists and then calculating those numbers into the spans. I have no access to the current option selection. I'm not seeming to get any values out of these variables above, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Oh, see that's what I meant by hard-coded. How are you accessing the variables, and which variables do you mean?

Comment: Also, if values are being read, where from exactly, and what does that code look like?

Comment: and if you check the codepen I included and view the console, you should see all of the checks' properties there.

Comment: Oh ok, I must have misunderstood the hard-coded question, sorry @Todd. I have tried accessing the option values by:
`var x = document.getElementsByTagName("option").getAttribute("value");
if (x === this.optionValue) {`
However, it doesn't seem like this is working either.. I will keep playing with that 
The values I was referring to in my previous comment were the object key values: pricePerCheck, priceBulk, etc.
I see that savings is working, but I can't seem to get any number values out of the others.

Comment: so by not working, do you mean the values are undefined

Comment: I think I've figured out a way (using jQuery) to grab my option values now: [OPTION VALUE GRAB](http://liveweave.com/7PeLXn) so I just need to now take that value, compare it with an object array and then change selectCheck to the object with the matching value.

Comment: yeah, man. If you still need to do the calculations after you create your object, for whatever reason, you'd need to add those as properties to the 'check' object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a `function` for `calculations` and call it no matter what first to get a value even when the first selection is being done. You will also need to call this `function` `onchange`. I have added a `div` for `savings` and fixed the calculations so the correct variables are being used.

```js
function selectedCheck(current_quantity, current_price, projected_quantity, projected_price, optionValue) {
    this.current_quantity = current_quantity;
    this.current_price = current_price;
    this.projected_quantity = projected_quantity;
    this.projected_price = projected_price;
    this.optionValue = function getValueFromOption() {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("option").each().getAttribute("value");
        if (x === optionValue) { 

            return x;

        }
  };
}

    /*Secure Plus Voucher Checks*/
    var checks = [
        new selectedCheck(50, 66.99, 250, 169.99, "1785-00050/check-11"),
        new selectedCheck(250, 169.99, 500, 230.99, "1785-00250/check-11"),
        new selectedCheck(500, 230.99, 1000, 327.99, "1785-00500/check-11"),
        new selectedCheck(1000, 327.99, 2000, 514.99, "1785-01000/check-11"),
        new selectedCheck(1000, 327.99, 2000, 514.99, "1785-02000/check-11"),
    ];

function calculations() {  
    /*Calculations*/
    var selected_check = checks[document.querySelector("select.priceDrp5").selectedIndex];
    var current_pricepercheck = (selected_check.current_price - selected_check.current_quantity).toFixed(2);
    var projected_pricepercheck = (selected_check.projected_price * selected_check.projected_quantity).toFixed(2)
    var current_price_bulk = (selected_check.current_price / selected_check.current_quantity * selected_check.projected_quantity).toFixed(2);
    var projected_price_bulk = (selected_check.projected_price / selected_check.projected_quantity * selected_check.projected_quantity ).toFixed(2);
    var savings = ( current_price_bulk - projected_price_bulk).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML = (savings);
}
calculations();
```

```html
<select class="priceDrp5" onchange="calculations()">
    <option value="1785-00050/check-11">50</option>
    <option selected="true" value="1785-00250/check-11">250</option>
    <option value="1785-00500/check-11">500</option> 
    <option value="1785-001000/check-11">1000</option>
    <option value="1785-002000/check-11">2000</option>
    </select>
<div id="savings"></div>
```